# How can a SE participant be congratulated in a big way?

Tags: support, reputation

A participant in a particular beta site is about to be the first to reach a major reputation milestone.  This participant is truly beloved on that site.  (The participant is not a moderator on the site.)  I'd like to do something really big to mark the occasion and celebrate.  Is this possible, for example by writing a guest post on an SE blog?

How about something like

[Congratulations: the big thread!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19135/373402)

but here on Meta?

---

Update: Well, he got there before I could figure out something grander, so I had to settle on using our local Meta to celebrate Spanish Language Beta's [first 50K superhero](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/users/12637/charlie), with a list of our chillin' champion Charlie's [Greatest Hits](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3098/9385). It's a milestone for Charlie but also for Spanish Language Beta!

[image: chillin' champion Charlie]

Comment: There is always Chat.

Comment: This was a nice idea on your side, aparente! A bit pretentious indeed  but still telling of how much you care for Charlie  Anyways, while I like that you took the trouble to ask this here in Meta.SE, the way you phrased it made it look like you're talking on Spanish.SE's behalf, which I'm sure was not your intention. Could you please edit to make it clear that this was an idea of yours to surprise Charlie? Thanks!! 

Comment: @walen - I see what you mean.  I switched *we* for *I* -- is that clearer now?

Comment: Yes @aparente001, it's perfect now, thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I've seen people post announcements on the local meta for celebrating users reaching milestones:

- [Congratulations to Joe Strazzere for 100k rep!](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3350)
- [Congratulations, Bill!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12317)
- [Congratulations, Yuval passed 200K!](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1630/44381)
- [Congratulations Luboš Motl](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4319)
- [Congratulations to our third 100k member of Sec.SE (first human member...)](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3017)
- https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2711
- https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4306/37236

Questions like this *usually* stay open when they're posted.

Answer (score 5):

First, I appreciate the fact you care enough to come here with such a thing.

However, keep in mind Stack Exchange got over 170 sites by now. Each of them has its own great users.

That means, among other things, that it's not feasible to thank a specific user in a company wide manner.

Jon Skeet is the one and only exception.

So several options that I can think of:

- Award bounties to outstanding answers of that user. Even with lots of rep, seeing those +50, +100, etc would likely be nice for them.
- Create a new chat room dedicated to thank that user, where you can also discuss off-site stuff with them. If I were that user, I'd be honored by such a thing and happily joining.
- If they publish contact details, suggest sending IRL gifts, e.g. via Amazon Gift Card.
- etc...

Comment: *Why* is Jon Skeet "the one and only exception"?

Comment: I think if another user reaches a million rep on a single site, SE will do something to acknowledge it.  I think the framed unicorn art that Jon got was unique and it won't be that, but I suspect they'll do *something*.

Comment: Jon isn't the one and _only_ exception; he's just currently _the one_ (I totally nailed adding clarity there with a Matrix reference so I'm going to go do a little dance).

Answer (score 5):

Various sites have rewarded users with prizes or other recognition, often this is for the top X users, or winners of some goal. And it's usually a prize related to that site - a tech item for a tech site etc

You could reward them with anything you like. What do you fancy? Do you want to club together to buy them something, or write a blog post, or just celebrate with a post on the meta for that site?

It's all suitable - just decide what you want and how to do it :-)