# Should the cross-site link title conversion limit be increased on this site?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, meta

I noticed [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/328843/377214) which has seven links to posts on different per-site metas.

When typing up the post in the *preview*, the post renders just fine, and all the links render correctly as titles:

> [image: All seven links to different sites render as titles]

But in the published post, only the first five links render as titles:

> [image: Only first five links render as titles]

At first, I was going to report this as a bug, but while typing this question, I discovered [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108475/377214) which states that it's intentional that only the first five links render as titles, as only a maximum of five other SE sites can be linked to and have their link titles converted to question titles.

This [is a known bug with the preview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301352/295232). (It might be possible that it doesn't even consider any limit, and also disregards the other limit of 200 links per site; can a 2k+ user on Stack Overflow in Russian please confirm to me if all the links in [this post](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7058/304679) render as titles in the edit preview and update that other post?)

Given this example, however, I'd like to discuss whether the limit should be increased. Here on Meta Stack Exchange, I envision the possibility that there may be legitimate reasons to have titled links to more than five other sites. This site is the only one where it's possible to hit the limit; on other sites, only cross-site links to 1-2 specific sites can be converted (specifically links to the corresponding per-site meta on main Q&A sites, and to the corresponding main site and Meta Stack Exchange on per-site metas; this site is the unique exception, where links to all main sites and per-site metas can be converted).

Therefore, should the 5-site limit for cross-site links be increased? Should the feature request at the bottom of the other post be implemented? Are there a lot of posts here that link to more than five other sites such that it justifies increasing the limit, or is the post above one of a few unique cases? I wanted to query for this in the Data Explorer, but writing a query for this [would be onerous](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7757900#7757900) due to its nature.

Comment: Related / duplicate (as far as the bug report goes): [Auto-rendering of links stops working after the fifth link … or does it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315993/295232) and [Either fix edit window display to render more than 5 links to questions correctly or convert all links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301352/295232)

Comment: @Glorfindel Edited this to only be a discussion about whether the link conversion limit should be increased here.